# Firefox extension error - value does not implement interface WindowProxy interface

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

```
var mouse = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
mouse.initMouseEvent("mousedown",true,false,window,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
```

The above code is present in my content script. But when this code is invoked, firefox throws following error. `An exception occurred. TypeError: Value does not implement interface WindowProxy`

I think I am passing invalid `window` object to `initMouseEvent`. But I don't see a way to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess passing `unsafeWindow` will do the trick.